# React Hook: The set function of useState does not trigger re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, rendering, react-hooks

I'm currently working on a simplified Trello clone project. I defined a `boardList` with `useState`, and implemented two functions `create()` and `remove()` which are capable of adding or deleting a board, list, or card. Everything works fine except when deleting a list.

When I click the button to delete a list, the component doesn't re-render instantly. Deleting boards and cards give instant changes. Just in the case of lists, it doesn't seem to re-render although the `boardList` has been modified to delete the list. The changes are applied when I go to the home page and get back. I'm curious why `setBoardList()` does not trigger render, only in this specific situation. My functions always provide a new object `newBoardList`, so it's probably not about returning the same object that react can't recognize.

Below is my `App.js` and `Board.js`. `Home` route shows the boards, and users can click any one of them to go into the `BoardPage` route and modify the lists and cards within the board. `Board.js` includes the `deleteList()` that is related to the problem.

You can see the full project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-lederberg-l3e3e

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import Home from './routes/Home';
import BoardPage from './routes/BoardPage';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
    }
`;

export const EMPTY =  '-';

function App() {
    const [boardList, setBoardList] = React.useState([]);
    const create = (boardKey, listKey, text) => {
      if(boardKey===EMPTY){ //createBoard
        const check = boardList.filter(board => board.boardName === text);
        if(!check.length && text.length){
            const newBoardList = boardList.concat([{boardKey: text.concat(Date.now()), boardName: text, listList: []}]);
            setBoardList(newBoardList);
        } 
      }
      else if(listKey===EMPTY){ //createList
        const newBoardList = [...boardList];
        newBoardList.forEach(board => {
          if(board.boardKey===boardKey){
            const check = board.listList.filter(list => list.listName === text);
            if(!check.length && text.length){
              board.listList.push({listKey: text.concat(Date.now()), listName: text, cardList: []});
            }
          }
        });
        setBoardList(newBoardList);
      }
      else{ //createCard
        const newBoardList = [...boardList];
        newBoardList.forEach(board => {
          if(board.boardKey===boardKey){
            board.listList.forEach(list => {
              if(list.listKey===listKey){
                const check = list.cardList.filter(card => card.content === text);
                if(!check.length && text.length){
                  list.cardList.push({cardKey: text.concat(Date.now()), content: text});
                }
              }
            });
          }
        });
        setBoardList(newBoardList);
      } 
    };


    const remove = (boardKey, listKey, cardKey) => {
      if(boardKey===EMPTY){
        return;
      }
      else{
        if(listKey===EMPTY){ //removeBoard
          const newBoardList = boardList.filter(board => board.boardKey !== boardKey);
          setBoardList(newBoardList);   
        }
        else if(cardKey===EMPTY){ //removeList
          const newBoardList = [...boardList];
          newBoardList.forEach(board => {
            if(board.boardKey===boardKey){
              board.listList = board.listList.filter(list => list.listKey !== listKey);
            }
          });
          setBoardList(newBoardList);
        }
        else{ //removeCard
          const newBoardList = [...boardList];
          newBoardList.forEach(board => {
            if(board.boardKey===boardKey){
              board.listList.forEach(list => {
                if(list.listKey===listKey){
                  list.cardList = list.cardList.filter(card => card.cardKey !== cardKey);
                }
              });
            }
          });
          setBoardList(newBoardList);
        }
      }
    };
    return (
        <>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <HashRouter>
              <Route path="/" exact={true} render={props => <Home {...props} boardList={boardList} create={create} remove={remove}/>} />
              <Route path="/board/:boardName" render={props => <BoardPage {...props} create={create} remove={remove} />} />
            </HashRouter>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Board.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import List from './List';
import {EMPTY} from '../App';

export default function Board({boardKey, boardName, listList, create, remove}) {
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const createNewList = text => {
        create(boardKey, EMPTY, text);
    };
    const deleteList = (key) => {
        remove(boardKey, key, EMPTY);
    };
    const onChange = e =>{
        setText(e.target.value);
    };
    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        createNewList(text);
        setText("");
    };
    return(
        <BoardContainer>
            <h4>{boardName}</h4>
            {listList.map(list => (
                <span key={list.listKey}>
                    <List boardKey={boardKey} listKey={list.listKey} listName={list.listName} cardList={list.cardList} create={create} remove={remove} />
                    <button onClick={()=>deleteList(list.listKey)}>DelL</button>
                </span>
            ))}
            <ListAdder>
                <input type="text" value={text} onChange={onChange} />
                <button onClick={onSubmit}>AddL</button>
            </ListAdder>
        </BoardContainer>
    );

}

const BoardContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
`;

const ListAdder = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid gray;
`;
```

Comment: Maybe a big ask, but can you get a working structure on a site like https://codesandbox.io/? Would help us replicate.

Comment: I just added a link. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are keeping the state in two separate places, making it inconsistent. You are passing `board.listList` as a  location state in the `Home` component, and this reference will not keep track of changes to the `boardList` in `App`.

I made an example here which seems to work as intended:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mclaren-pv2s2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

In the code I linked, we are not passing the list in the location state anymore, but passing the `boardList` to the `BoardPage` and extracting the proper board from there based on the `boardKey`. This allows us to always access the current state.

There are of course multiple ways you can do this and you might prefer a different style than my example. Just make sure to pass the actual state and not create a separate reference to it.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!